# nested dictionaries and regex for sorting a play into lines of dialogue

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I am working in Python 3.6.3 to take a TV/Play/whatever script and sort it into a dictionary which pairs characters and their lines of dialogue.

I have been able to get the result I want, which nests `{Line#:Line}` pairs for each `Character:`, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to go about getting to this point. Specifically itis the way in which I am initially splitting up the text, I first get lists of the individual words of the dialogue, and then join these list by iterating through a copy of the dictionary.

```
import re

text = """
Steve: Is that his chart? 
Phil: Yes. 
Steve: Mm-hmm. I'll see him in a few moments. 
Phil: All right. Thank you, Doctor. 
P.A.: Dr. Braun, Dr. Miller, and Dr. Sullivan, emergency. 
Steve: How is she, Jessie? 
Jessie: Still fighting everybody and everything. She wants to live in the 
dark and never see her face again. That's about what she was doing when I went 
in. She had the blinds all drawn, towel over the mirror. """
## general hospital!    

dialog = {}
count = 0
cast = []
for word in text.split():
    if re.match(".*\:", word):
        character = word[:-1]
        count += 1      
        if character not in dialog:
            cast.append(character)
            dialog[character] = {}
            dialog[character][count] = []
        else:
            dialog[character][count] = []
    else:
        dialog[character][count].append(word)


fullLines = {}
for k,v in dialog.items(): 
    fullLines[k] = {}
    for k1,v1 in v.items():
        v1 = ' '.join(v1)
        fullLines[k][k1] = v1
```

Is there a way I could split the text using regex to identify the dialogue prompts - "Character:" and split the text with that? I tried placing
`re.compile(r".*\:")` into `split()` like so

```
match = re.compile(".*\:")
for word in text.split(match):
```

and got the error `TypeError: must be str or None, not _sre.SRE_Pattern`. So I basically understand why that doesn't work. I am still learning python, so I am still accumulating methods and pythonic habits.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: this is what I currently get:

Comment: ` {'Steve': {1: 'Is that his chart?', 3: "Mm-hmm. I'll see him in a few moments.", 6: 'How is she, Jessie?'}, 'Phil': {2: 'Yes.', 4: 'All right. Thank you, Doctor.'}, 'P.A.': {5: 'Dr. Braun, Dr. Miller, and Dr. Sullivan, emergency.'}, 'Jessie': {7: "Still fighting everybody and everything. She wants to live in the dark and never see her face again. That's about what she was doing when I went in. She had the blinds all drawn, towel over the mirror."}} `

Comment: which is what I was aiming for, but I was wondering if I am getting there in an overly complicated manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following expression

```
^                             # start of the line
(?P<actor>[A-Z][^:\n\r]+):\s* # a potential actor
(?P<text>[\s\S]+?)            # the following text
(?=^[A-Z]|\Z)                 # lookaheads for the text
```

in combination with a nested `defaultdict` as container. The only thing left is to calculate the line numbers by counting the newline characters up to that point (as defined by the `match` object).

See a demo for the expression on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/CTfXNJ/1).

---

In `Python` this could be:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

string = """Steve: Is that his chart? 
Phil: Yes. 
Steve: Mm-hmm. I'll see him in a few moments. 
Phil: All right. Thank you, Doctor. 
P.A.: Dr. Braun, Dr. Miller, and Dr. Sullivan, emergency. 
Steve: How is she, Jessie? 
Jessie: Still fighting everybody and everything. She wants to live in the 
dark and never see her face again. That's about what she was doing when I went 
in. She had the blinds all drawn, towel over the mirror."""

rx = re.compile(r'''
    ^
    (?P<actor>[A-Z][^:\n\r]+):\s*
    (?P<text>[\s\S]+?)
    (?=^[A-Z]|\Z)
    ''', re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)

# create the nested defaultdict
result = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))

for m in rx.finditer(string):
    start = m.start()
    line = string.count('\n', 0, start) + 1
    result[m.group('actor')][line] = m.group('text').strip()

print(result)
```

This yields

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x10ffe0e18>, {'Steve': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {1: 'Is that his chart?', 3: "Mm-hmm. I'll see him in a few moments.", 6: 'How is she, Jessie?'}), 'Phil': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {2: 'Yes.', 4: 'All right. Thank you, Doctor.'}), 'P.A.': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {5: 'Dr. Braun, Dr. Miller, and Dr. Sullivan, emergency.'}), 'Jessie': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {7: "Still fighting everybody and everything. She wants to live in the \ndark and never see her face again. That's about what she was doing when I went \nin. She had the blinds all drawn, towel over the mirror."})})
```

Comment: THANKS. particularly for the link/demo. I am trying to practice regex, and it is slowly sinking in. The concept of named capture groups is really handy. There are a number of concepts and methods, such as start() and finditer(). A lot of useful bits to follow up on...

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions and `itertools.groupby`:

```
import re
import itertools
text = """
Steve: Is that his chart? 
Phil: Yes. 
Steve: Mm-hmm. I'll see him in a few moments. 
Phil: All right. Thank you, Doctor. 
P.A.: Dr. Braun, Dr. Miller, and Dr. Sullivan, emergency. 
Steve: How is she, Jessie? 
Jessie: Still fighting everybody and everything. She wants to live in the dark and never see her face again. That's about what she was doing when I went in. She had the blinds all drawn, towel over the mirror. """
parts = [[a, i, b] for i, [a, b] in enumerate([re.split(':\s*', i) for i in filter(None, text.split('\n'))], start = 1)]
final_parts = {a:dict([i[1:] for i in b]) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(parts, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])}
```

Output:

```
{'Steve': {1: 'Is that his chart? ', 3: "Mm-hmm. I'll see him in a few moments. ", 6: 'How is she, Jessie? '}, 'Jessie': {7: "Still fighting everybody and everything. She wants to live in the dark and never see her face again. That's about what she was doing when I went in. She had the blinds all drawn, towel over the mirror. "}, 'Phil': {2: 'Yes. ', 4: 'All right. Thank you, Doctor. '}, 'P.A.': {5: 'Dr. Braun, Dr. Miller, and Dr. Sullivan, emergency. '}}
```

Comment: thanks! your solution is quite concise, and offers me a bunch to learn from. The one component I am not certain about is the `text.split('\n')` does this require formating the script so that a characters lines have no breaks?

Comment: @AyO multiline strings inherently contain the `\n` characters, so you should not need to preformat your text unless you are reading the data from a file, database, etc.